# How to write the definition of a derived class in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual

I don't know the  syntax for writing the definition of a class function with templates.

I get an error, the complier expected ; , so that be 
void plus; 
Anyone knows to fix that!

```
template<class Type 
class basic{
 protected:
    Type x;
 public:
    int value;
    //virtual void  print() =0; 
  basic(Type xArg):x(xArg){}
}; 

template<class Type>
class plus:public basic<Type>{
 public: 
  Type y;
  plus(Type xArg, Type yArg):basic<Type>(xArg),y(yArg){}
  void print(); 

};

//template<class Type> 
void plus<Type>::print(){ 
  cout << "x : " << x << endl;
  cout << "y : " << y << endl;

}
```

Comment: What happens if you uncomment the `//template<class Type>` line?

Comment: Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: the problem still, it would not fix that

Comment: The error you're mentioning seems to not be present for me: https://godbolt.org/z/T8K08a

Comment: `template<class Type ` you simply forgot the closing `>`

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members

Comment: BTW it's "in advance", not "in advanced"

Comment: Thank you for noticing  , that was a good catch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a base class:

```
template<class T> 
class MyBase {
   public:
    T value;

    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "MyBase.value: " << value;
    }        
    virtual ~MyBase() = default; 
};
```

We can derive it and override `print` like this. It doesn't have to be a template, but I'm using one in the example.

```
template<class T>
class MyDerived : MyBase<T>
{
   public:
    void print() override {
        std::cout << "MyDerived.value: " << MyBase<T>::value;
    }
};
```

In addition, something I like to do is use `base` to represent the base class:

```
template<class T>
class MyDerived : MyBase<T>
{
   public:
    using base = MyBase<T>; // Use this to indicate the base
    void print() override {
        std::cout << "MyDerived.value: " << base::value << '\n';
    }
};
```

Comment: Sure thing! I hope it helps!